# KeepAliveAgent HTTP agent with full control over socket pool in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, keep-alive

Is there any library for Node where one can have full control over every socket used by an http keep-alive agent?

Full control: One have all info about each socket and can kill it and spam a new one in case of hitting slow backend/routing